# How to Display Custom Post Type's Gallery (images ) in Through WP_Query

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-query, loop, gallery

I am trying to load an Image Slider images from a Custom Post Type image Gallery Feature. For example let say I have an Custom Post Type called banner which I can load images to it's Gallery and I have an HTML code like this:

```
<div class="item active">
  <img src="assets/img/ban1r.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    slide 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item active">
  <img src="assets/img/ban2r.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    slide 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you please let me know how I can use the custom WP_Query to retrive the images from the custom post and load them into slider instead of above HTML?

So far I have done something like this but it is not displaying any image!

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'banner');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $gallery = get_post_gallery_images($post);
foreach( $gallery as $image ) {
       echo '<div class="item active">';
       echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';
       echo '</div>';
    }
endwhile;
?>
```

**Update:**
The Result of `var_dump($POST)`
[image]

Comment: Can you place `var_dump($post);` somewhere in the loop to see what we have inside post object?

Comment: Hi Kristian, I updated the code with var_dump($post); please take a look at the attached image

Comment: Can some one please help me to fix this?

Comment: Please? any solutions or hint!

Comment: What is `var_dump($gallery);`? But honestly that should work, and does when I test it.

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum I really appriciate for your time and sorry for late reply. I tried to run the code with 'var_dump($gallery);' and the result is array(0) {}. Seriously?! did it work for you? how come it is not working for me? once again thanks