# Cant' Grab WordPress Built-in Posts Through Loop

Tags: posts, plugin-development, theme-development, loop

Using WordPress 3.7.1 I am trying to display all Regular Post on my created page lest say TestPage. Here are the steps I took to do this:

**1-** Generate a Custom Page Template called:Test Page and loaded by following code
**2-** Generate a Page Called TestPage based on Test Page Template

after updating the page I am not getting any of Post on the page while I have already generated some!

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Test Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1>  
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, this page does not exist</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

he abouve code actually is loading the page whit title and content of the TestPage and not by Posts!Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: Just to be sure the basics are covered, have you selected your Test Page as your Posts Page in Settings > Reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please let me know why this is happening?

A loop like yours assumes the data from the "main query". You've created a custom page template so the main query on that page is going to be the single "TestPage" data. That is the way it is supposed to work. That is, `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` doesn't always give you the post archive data.

To get the posts you'd need to create a new query and loop over that. Like this:

```
$newq = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post'));
if ($newq->have_posts()) {
  while ($newq->have_posts()) {
    $newq->the_post();
    the_title();
  }
}
```

You should probably look over the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) carefully, because this may not be the way you want to go about things at all.

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum, Thanks for you perfect explanation , I got it now

Comment: My code is more an example than a finished piece of code. You will have to take it and alter it to fit your needs.

Comment: Can you please take alook at this link and let me know how to fix this issue this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120882/how-to-display-custom-post-types-gallery-images-in-through-wp-query

Comment: I already Google this but couldn't find any solutions!